# sync account across multiple tabs using @auth0/auth0-react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

I've developed React application and login feature using `@auth0/auth0-react` and now I'm developing website in Next JS login feature using `@auth0/auth0-react` now I want to access same user across both app and website so now I've integrated login feature using auth0 and can sync between both app and website but while I'm logged out then can't logout from other using auth0....

`getAccessTokenSilently` gives me token which is different from another tab so after using `logout()` function of auth0 it can't logout from another tab.....
login is working fine but logout is not

my code of logout for both :

**Application:**

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const handleLogout = (e: any) => {
  localStorage.clear();
  logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } });
};
```

**Website:**

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

 const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: "http://localhost:3001" } });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is exactly your requirement but let me give you an idea of how `auth0` login and logout works with `react`

Checking for authentication in your App

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently, user } = useAuth0();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      getAccessTokenSilently().then((token) => {
         //If you want to store the token or call an API with the access_token
      })
    };
  }, [isAuthenticated])

  return (
   <>Your JSX</>
  )
}
```

Login:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const Login = () => {
    const { loginWithPopup, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();
    //IsLoading can be used to show a loading screen while the authentication is being performed

    async function handleLogin(){
        await loginWithPopup()
        //Other conditions
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            //Some condition such as navigating to a particular page
        }
    }, [isAuthenticated])

    return (
        <button
            onClick={handleLogin}
        >
            Login

        </button>
    )
```

Logout:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

const LogOutBtn = () => {
  const { logout, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  
  function handleLogoutEvent() {
    logout()
  }

  return (
    (isAuthenticated) 
     ? <button onClick={handleLogoutEvent}>
          Log Out
      </button>
     <>Some other condition</>
  )
}
```

Comment: Chinmay, your answer is absolutely correct but my requirement is different I'm updating my question so you can get better idea.